# Flamenco guitar books - is there a classic?

Tags: guitar, flamenco

I want to buy a book about learning to play flamenco guitar. Is there a classic? A book that everybody agrees on as being the must-have for every flamenco player? 
Of course I appreciate any good resources, be it "the classic" or not.

Comment: AIUI Flamenco developed from both Spanish Classical and Gypsy folk music. The folk component of course has no *method* per se, but there are "classic" methods from Spanish masters Sor, Tarrega, Segovia, and similar works from the Italians Aguado, Carcassi, Legnani (no method, I think, but some brilliant "Spanish" pieces, very relevant to Flamenco technique and style IMO). Many of these are available at imslp.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although maybe not especially for flamenco.The Christopher Parkening Guitar Method book 1 and 2 is considered a classical guitar must have. Also the Suzuki guitar books give a good systematic approach to guitar playing.

Although these books are classical you can learn enough from them to eventually put what you learn towards flamenco music. The techniques are at the very least somewhat complimentary.